# Security Vulnerabilities without <meta chartset=<<"any-encoding">> /> tag?

Tags: html, security, web, character-encoding, xss

I have read somewhere that it is good practice to declare the character set

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

of your document to protect against a serious security risk.

what are the risks if someone don't define character set in html document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a class of XSS known as [UTF-7 XSS](http://openmya.hacker.jp/hasegawa/security/utf7cs.html).

Under this encoding `+ADw-` renders as `<` and `+AD4-` renders as `>`. This makes it possible for an attacker to inject

```
+ADw-script+AD4-alert(document.location)+ADw-/script+AD4-
```

and have it rendered and interpreted by the browser as

```
<script>alert(document.location)</script>
```

.
Old versions of Internet Explorer auto detect the charset. Therefore, if no charset is specified in a response header or a meta tag then the output of sequences such as `+ADw` "trick" Internet Explorer into rendering the page using UTF-7 making any such injected script execute. This gives rise to the XSS vulnerability.