# Is there charset encoding vulnerability in 2022?

Tags: security, character-encoding, http-headers, xss, content-type

Does not specifying the charset in the content-type of the http response header lead to vulnerability, even in modern web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) as of 2022?

I read the following article, but as of 2022, due to the efforts of web browser vendors, XSS attacks using utf-7 are no longer valid, and although garbled characters may occur, they will not be a vulnerability.

https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/6-Appendix/D-Encoded_Injection

[Security Vulnerabilities without <meta chartset=<<"any-encoding">> /> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834152/security-vulnerabilities-without-meta-chartset-any-encoding-tag)

Answer (score 1):

By default HTML5 uses UTF-8 character set. UTF-7 and previous as I understand had the Accept-Charset flag which wasn't entirely safe as character slipping was a nightmare.

Check out this Firefox Mozilla article : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation